# Dynamic color jasper

Tags: java, colors, jasper-reports, javabeans

I am developing a report on Jaspersoft Studio 6.4.0 and I use JavaBeans as data sources.

I need to change the background color of a textfield dynamically. In fact I have a color variable in my bean which is calculated like this :

```
Color resultColor = new Color(255, (int) (ratio * 5.1), 0);
```

Where ratio is a double calculated with the variable in the textfield.

I have two possibilities, the first one is to give a Color to my jasper report and the second one is to calculate the green and red ratio and make the color in
a conditionnal style. 
I don't know where I can put this kind of dynamic color, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find the solution:

```
<propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor"> 
    <![CDATA["#" + net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRColorUtil.getColorHexa($F‌​{resultColor})]]> 
</propertyExpression>
```

With resultColor a *java.awt.color*. You need to put this in your report element.

I find the solution [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/crosstabs/index.html#dynamic_style_features)